# Using ADO to connect to Access database from Excel error 3704

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

When I use the code below to connect to an access database from Excel, I get error 3704 "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed." at line

```
Call .Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset(rstRecordSet)
```

I can 'fix' this problem by commenting out the line

```
adoConnection.Close
```

but I really don't like that, or understand why it solves the problem.

Can anyone explain what's wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

```
Private Const constStrDBPath As String = "H:\Projects\DP.mdb"
Private Const constStrConnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                             "Data Source=" & constStrDBPath & ";" & _
                             "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                             "Persist Security Info=False;"


Public Function SelectStatement(strCommandText As String) As Object

    Dim adoConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim adoCommand As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rstRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset

    adoCommand.CommandText = strCommandText

    adoConnection.Open constStrConnection
    adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

    'create the recordset by executing command string
    Set rstRecordSet = adoCommand.Execute(, , adadoCommandText)

    Set SelectStatement = rstRecordSet

    ' clean up
    adoConnection.Close
    Set rstRecordSet = Nothing
    Set adoConnection = Nothing
    Set adoCommand = Nothing

End Function

Sub TestSelect()

    Dim rstRecordSet As Object
    Dim lngField As Long

    Set rstRecordSet = SelectStatement("SELECT * FROM tblSystem")

    If Not rstRecordSet Is Nothing Then
        With Sheet1.Range("A1")
            For lngField = 1 To rstRecordSet.Fields.Count
                .Cells(1, lngField).Value = rstRecordSet.Fields(lngField - 1).Name
            Next lngField
            Call .Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset(rstRecordSet)
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: assuming you have a client-side cursor, I think you just need to set the recordset's ActiveConnection to Nothing before you close the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function SelectStatement is not fetching (reading) anything from the database.

In plain terms your actual SelectStatement() opens a channel with Access, prepares the query, sets a cursor and then throws away all.

The cleanup phase has to be postponed after having read the last recordset.

Comment: I'd misunderstood how the recordset object worked. Both replies have pointed me in the right direction and I think with some work I'll get there now. Thanks.